# string replace backslash with slash

Tags: go

I need to replace `\` with `/` in a path string, but following code failed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    string := "P:\Project\project-name/content/topic/"
    fmt.Println(strings.Replace(string, "\\", "/", -1))
}
```

Any helpful suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the function [filepath.ToSlash](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#ToSlash) to replace the operating system path separator with '/' in a path.

On Windows, the function returns `strings.Replace(path, string(filepath.Separator), "/", -1)`.  On other operating systems, the function returns the path argument as is.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't escape backslashes in `string`. The following code works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    string := "P:\\Project\\project-name/content/topic/"
    fmt.Println(strings.Replace(string, "\\", "/", -1))
}
```

Play this on playground: https://play.golang.org/p/T3XE5uiIkk

Answer (score 1):

You can also use back-quotes (`` ` ``) to create a raw string:

```
func main() {
    string := `P:\Project\project-name/content/topic/`
    fmt.Println(strings.Replace(string, "\\", "/", -1))
}
```

Note that the raw string above would still have its internal representation as

```
"P:\\Project\\project-name/content/topic/"
```

Hence the need to use `"\\"` in `strings.Replace` function.

Comment: Is it possible to simply convert the literal string to raw string programmatically before the replacement?

Comment: @kOssi a raw string is just a way to represent a literal string without needing those pesky double backslashes. That's what abhink means when he says that they have the same internal representation. They're not two different types, or even two different strings. They're syntactic sugar to make things easier on the programmer's eyes.