# Escape backlash golang

Tags: go

How can I escape the inverted bar without replacing it?. it's possible?

something like @"\file" in C#.

```
stringValues :='C:\Users\PC\go\src\dss-persistence\files\fileA'
hash, err := hash_file_md5(os.Args[0])
if err == nil {
    fmt.Println(hash)
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995913/string-replace-backslash-with-slash) might help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string replace backslash with slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995913/string-replace-backslash-with-slash)

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs this is not an duplicate of the problem you specified

Comment: See https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals

Comment: I found this way ,without using doble backslash or remplace: [using (`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39996077/9179487)

Comment: @Josueferrufino If that helped you, then you can click the button which states: "This solved my problem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this way ,without using doble backslash or remplace: [using (`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39996077/9179487)